# How do I ask a question and make a comment in the same sentence?

Tags: sentence, questions, offensive-language, syntactic-analysis

For example, if I wanted to ask somebody a question and call them an idiot would I write:
"What do you know about grammar? You Idiot" or "What do you know about grammar you idiot?"

Or is it done completely differently?
Thanks.

Comment: Why am I asking you- what could an idiot possibly know about grammar?

Comment: Probably best not to do it.

Comment: If you need to ask the question, perhaps you should redirect the insult!

Comment: This is why I think English needs a question-comma! Basically a question mark with the full stop replaced with a comma.

Answer (score 3):

To be syntactically correct, although just as rude:

> What do you know about grammar, you idiot?

Insert a comma after the word grammar.  After all, this is not a sentence you want to get wrong, grammatically or otherwise.
Having said that, I would find a nicer way to convey the sentiment.  You are, after all, not truly interested in what they know about grammar, but rather in telling them they are an idiot.
It seems pointless to find the proper way to have a fruitless conversation.